# call Object out of scope C++

Tags: c++, object, scope

I am making a simple text based rouge game. In my code I created a class for "rooms" and I create an instance of a room named 'Dungeon' in my main file. The problem arises with this objects scope. I have created it in a 'initGame()' function but then I cannot have access to it in the main game loop.

I shall post all relevant code, Thanks!

room.h

```
#include <string>
#include "ConsoleCommands.h"
using std::string;


class room
{
public:
    room(void);
    room(string name);
    ~room(void);

        //This creates the cells and populates the map//
    static const int cellsX = 15;
    static const int cellsY = 10;

    string NAME;
    int map;

    void writeMap();
};
```

main.cpp

```
int main(void)
{
    initGame();
    cout << "WELCOME, " + Player.NAME + " ";
    return 0;
};

void initGame(void)
{
    initCells();
    lifeForm Player(100, 100, 100, newGameMenu());
    room Dungeon("Dungeon");
}
```

Comment: Avoid (pun intended) `void` for functions with no parameters. Thats C, and works in C++ for compatibility only. Just write `()`.

Comment: ah, thank you I did not know this (self taught newbie). will fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dungeon and Player get destructed when initGame returns. Return the room and/or Player instances from the function.

You could use a Game struct like:

```
struct Game
{
    Game() : Player(100, 100, 100, newGameMenu()), Dungeon("Dungeon")
    {
    }

    lifeForm Player;
    room Dungeon;
}
```

then

```
int main(void)
{
    Game g;
    cout << "WELCOME, " + g.Player.NAME + " ";
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Wow, I feel silly. I don't know why I didn't think of researching that.. works like a charm now, thank you so much.

Comment: @EricFortin any chance you could explain the ':' operator to me? I understand if not.

Comment: It is the initializer list. Full objects need to be constructed by the contructor. If you put a line like: Player = lifeform(100, 100, 100, newGameMenu()) in your constrictor, the object will be constructed once and then assigned with a new value. By using the initializer list, they get constructed once with the value you want.

Comment: Ah, this makes since. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As you have correctly stated, the problem is scope. The objects

```
lifeForm Player(100, 100, 100, newGameMenu());
room Dungeon("Dungeon");
```

only exist inside the scope of

```
void initGame(void)
```

To deal with this, you can try a few things

1)  Initialize objects in main.  Simply move the declarations from initGame() to main.  This is not very modular, you'd like to have the initialization code in a function called init.

2)  Create initialization code in an init function, and return the objects to main.  Have initRoom() and initLifeForm() create as before, and then return objects of types room and lifeForm respectively.  Then in main copy them either through a initializer or using =.

```
int main(void)
{
   room theRoom = initRoom();
   lifeForm theLifeForm = initLifeForm();
}
```

this is not much better than 1) or maybe even worse, but at least you have removed speific initialization to the init function.  Of course in this case why not have special no-argument  initialization constructors for this purpose?

3)  Have a Game object.  This is probably what you want.  Here room and lifeForm become members of Game, and initGame is the Game constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your initGame function creates some local objects

```
void initGame(void)
{
    initCells();
    lifeForm Player(100, 100, 100, newGameMenu());
    room Dungeon("Dungeon");
}
```

Lets take a quick look at one of these statements:

```
room Dungeon("Dungeon");
```

This is a variable declaration, but C++ uses scoping, which means context matters. The scope here is inside a function, so what you are doing is declaring an instance of "room", to be called "Dungeon", and to be constructed by calling `room::room(std::string)`.

In C++, local objects are declared on the stack - this means that as the program unwinds the stack as you leave a scope, those objects are going to be forced to go away.

So, if you were to C-ify the above statement, this is roughly the code you would produce:

```
void initGame(void)
{
    initCells();

    lifeForm* Player = alloca(sizeof(Player));
    Player->lifeForm(100, 100, 100, newGameMenu());

    room* Dungeon = alloca(sizeof(Dungeon));
    std::string dungeonName = std::string("Dungeon");
    Dungeon->room(dungeonName);

    // scope ends
    // destruct Dungeon
    Dungeon->~room();

    // destruct Player
    player->~lifeForm();

    // the stack space is automatically "released" by
    // leaving the function
}
```

The upshot here is that the objects have completely gone away. If you want them to persist, you will need to manage their lifetime either by returning them, declaring them in main and passing them by reference to functions that need them, or encapsulating them in an object of their own.

Answer (score -1):

If you're going to use these variables often, you can create them as global variables outside of any function:

```
lifeForm g_Player;
room g_Dungeon;

int main(void)
{
    initGame();
    cout << "WELCOME, " + Player.NAME + " ";
    return 0;
};

void initGame(void)
{
    initCells();
    g_Player = Player(100, 100, 100, newGameMenu());
    g_Dungeon = Dungeon("Dungeon");
}
```

Then, whenever you need to access these objects after init game, you use the global object

```
void Death(void)
{
    g_Player.Lives--;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. I removed the null initialization. The -1 was unnecessary though, a simple comment pointing out the mistake would have sufficed.